# Color the background of a cell in ng-grid with rgb value in data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid and I have a database that contains a column with rgb values such as #fc3b25, etc.  I need to set the background color of each cell in the rgb column to the value contained in the database. In the libraryGrid, I have defined the columnDes as follows:

```
{
    field: 'rgb',
    displayName: 'Key',
    width: '50px',
    cellTemplate: "<div style='height:60px; width:50px; background-color: {{ row.getProperty('rgb') }} ;' >rgb</div>"
}
```

This does not work.  It seems that a directive might be appropriate here, but I haven't had any success there either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you put it in an `ng-style` does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Write your celltemplate like this:

```
{field:'rgb', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<div style="background-color:{{row.entity.rgb}}" ><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}]
```

[Look here for a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AM6JuSXZCQ9NkYpbBSUU?p=preview)