# How could i display the ng-grid cell data based on various conditions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ng-if

I have a grid display in HTML page with dynamic data display in gird ,I want to display 7 colors  in a third cell of every row in the grid ,based on the condition i have to display the colors , i am using if conditions for checking the conditions for colors .How could i display the colors in the third cell of every row of grid based on conditions  in angular.
In the following pluker eg code

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/AM6JuSXZCQ9NkYpbBSUU?p=preview,`
```

But i have toshow multiple colors in a single cell based on conditions ,my target image would be [image: target image]

In this for moroni displaying 2 color buttons based on conditions.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I am new to angularjs ,right now i have only demo grid ,I have to display those colors based on condition in the specific cell in the grid .

Comment: Maybe my answer from here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013985/color-the-background-of-a-cell-in-ng-grid-with-rgb-value-in-data/23016704#23016704 Look at the Plunker.

Comment: yah,but i have to display all the colors in the single cell for all the rows ,based on the condition the color have to display .

Comment: Hard to imagine what you want. Can you draw a picture?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AM6JuSXZCQ9NkYpbBSUU?p=preview,

Comment: In the plkr ,for Moroni i have to display all the colors one color below another color like button with colors  instead of red color in pluker ,all the colors display based on conditions.

Comment: @mainguy ,could you got what i want based on information .

Comment: for instance server side data contains Id,if id = 1,show white,id=2 show black and orange,if id = 3 show yellow and white only,like this multiple conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58595/discussion-between-user3812457-and-mainguy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uHED04yhWK92fKBARBDC?p=preview)

The colorbars are defined in the css and are applied to some state variables in the data-scope.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    state1: true
  }, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    state1: false,
    state2: true,
    state3: false
  }, {
    name: "Jacob",
    state1: true,
    state2: true,
    state3: false
  }, {
    name: "Nephi",
    state1: false,
    state2: true,
    state3: true
  }, {
    name: "Enos",
    state1: true,
    state2: true,
    state3: true
  }];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    rowHeight: 40,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      field: 'rgb',
      displayName: 'Age',
      cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{redbar: row.entity.state1,whitebar:!row.entity.state1}" ></div>' +
        '<div ng-class="{greenbar: row.entity.state2,whitebar:!row.entity.state2}" ></div>' +
        '<div ng-class="{bluebar: row.entity.state3,whitebar:!row.entity.state3}" ></div>'
    }]
  };
```

As you can see I only used three states and the respective colorbars since it's monday and I am still tired and lazy.:-)

Also note that I adjusted the `rowHeight` to fit all bars in one Cell. After adjusting the css with heights, margins and paddings, you should do this too.

Comment: your answer is acceptable but i want check id data, it is dynamic so how could i place true or false  ,how  could i check dynamically.Thank you for your guide lines .